# Cyclometric equation $x\arcsin x=1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What method should I use to solve following equation for $x$ $$
x\arcsin x=1?
$$
I would be grateful for any comment.

Comment: Just a heads up, as everyone is doing it, please refrain from using the tag "real-analysis" for whatever considers calculus. Real analysis is not calculus and not algebra or pre-algebra or whatever. Secondly, do you have any thoughts on the given problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your remark. My idea was try to write it as $$sin(\frac{1}{x})=x,$$ because $x\neq 0$ and $sin$ is inverse to $arcsin$ on $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. The answer given below is smooth.

Answer (score 3):

$$x\arcsin x = 1 \implies \arcsin x = \frac{1}{x} \implies \sin \frac{1}{x} = x$$

There isn't a good way to solve this, so I guess you can estimate using the MacLaurin expansion of $\sin x$.

$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-... \implies \sin \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3!x^3}+\frac{1}{5!x^5}-...$$

You can truncate the series at a point to estimate for $x$. For example, you can solve

$$\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3!x^3} = x$$

which gives $x \approx \pm0.888$ (true) and $x \approx \pm0.46$ (extraneous). You can use more terms for a more accurate estimate.

Comment: The value $\pm 0.46$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Yeah, I labelled it as extraneous.

Comment: It needs some justification on why it shall not be accepted (my opinion). Generally it's a bad exercise from the start, your solution elaboration is smooth (+1).

Comment: No problem! (And yes, it's not a very good exercise.) I also accidentally forgot to edit the expansion for $\sin \frac{1}{x}$, which I've now done. (In case it caused any confusion or anything.)